# The following classes could not be instantiated: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView

Tags: android, xml

Problem:

The following classes could not be instantiated: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView

Here is the hint provided by IDE.

```
 Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  


Tip: Try to refresh the layout.
```

Here is my fragment_comment_list.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="@string/title_best_comments"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_primary"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/best_comments_rv"
            android:name="com.opera.android.news.comment.CommentFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:context="com.opera.android.news.comment.CommentFragment"
            tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_comment" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="@string/title_latest_comments"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_primary"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/latest_comments_rv"
            android:name="com.opera.android.news.comment.CommentFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:context="com.opera.android.news.comment.CommentFragment"
            tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_comment" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Here is my fragment_comment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/comment_large_head"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_comment_head_large" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/comment_large_head"
            android:text="Romain Beaumont" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comment_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/name"
            android:layout_below="@id/name"
            android:text="7h" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/name"
            android:layout_below="@+id/comment_time"
            android:text="The previous deal was rejected by the Colombian people in a popular vote on 2 October.The previous deal was" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/comment_like_iv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_comment_unlike" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/comment_like_iv"
            android:text="32" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/replies"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the trace stack.

> Exception Details java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getValue(Resources_Delegate.java:747)
>     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1286)   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.createDrawableIfNeeded(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:234)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:54)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:66)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:56)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)   at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.support.Adapter.onCreateViewHolder  at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6078)   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5248)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5158)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2061)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1445)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1408)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:580)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3379)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure_Original(RecyclerView.java:2906)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:-1)
>     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
>     at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
>     at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
>     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)   at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)   at
>   android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1420)
>     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)   at
>   android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure_Original(NestedScrollView.java:482)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:-1)
>     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
>     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)   at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)   at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
>     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
>     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731) Copy stack to
>   clipboard   Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/ic_comment_unlike (23
>   similar errors not shown)  Failed to convert
>   @drawable/ic_comment_unlike into a drawable (Details) (21 similar
>   errors not shown)

Answer (score 0):

its seems like you haven't initialize ImageView.
or could you please show me your java code.?

Comment: I'm getting this error right now, is not a runtime error, is an android studio error message showing in the layout editor.